# How to get SQL execution to prompt for Query Parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Using Visual Studios inbuilt tool to connect to a DB for a SQL file you can execute queries against a database.

I use embedded queries in my C# assemblies, I develop these queries with query parameters and use Dapper to quickly map these queries to objects.

This works well, and you get intellisense while writing SQL, however, you can't execute these SQL files because the query parameters aren't defined within the raw query ( they will be provided by Dapper ), but it would seem it it could prompt for the query parameters.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this in Visual Studio, or if there are any tricks to doing this.

I could put them in the SQL file for testing, but I don't really like the idea because there is always a chance you accidently leave them in the file.

So typically I'd have a sql file that looks like :-

```
SELECT * from Blah where Blah.Id = @Id
```

If executed it will say that it doesn't know what Id is and there is no way to define Id other than to put a DECLARE statement into the SQL

So is there a way to get visual studio to prompt for query parameters? Or a trick to specifying a query parameter without putting them directly into the file?

Comment: I don't understand your situation yet, but how about Environment Variable?

Comment: I can't see how you'd use one....

Comment: why the vote to close?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around this problem in a way that works for my situation, but won't work in general

Given I embed my SQL into my code as an embedded resource, when I load the SQL I can post process the SQL.  That means in my SQL files I can do

```
DECLARE @Id int = 123

-- QUERY
SELECT * from Blah where Blah.Id = @Id
```

now I can run my query in visual studio against my database with test parameters, and when the real code loads the queries from the embedded resources, it strips anything before the `--QUERY` comment out.  It also double checks to make sure there are no DECLARE statements as I don't tend to use them in my sql queries with Dapper.

It makes for a nice workflow as you can build and test your queries quite quickly.